# Eigen segfaults with AVX on Ivy Bridge when using `std::vector` of fixed-size matrices

Tags: c++, vectorization, eigen, eigen3

I'm wondering if this is a known issue; if not, has anyone experienced this, and has anyone managed to find a fix?

I'm building a numerical computation code using Eigen 3.3.4 using GCC 6.4 on Fedora 25 on a Core i7-3700. My proc/cpuinfo says I should have AVX. I've tried two builds. Build 1:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O3 -m64 -mavx
```

and build 2:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O3 -m64 -msse4.2
```

Build 2 runs fine. But when I try build 1, I get segfaults in the `Zero` function for a square fixed-size matrix as well as in the `inverse()` method. I'll appreciate any pointers as to what might be going on.

EDIT: I forgot one very important detail: I was actually using a `std::vector` of fixed-size Eigen matrices.

Comment: Sounds like undefined behavior. Could you post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2):

The fact that I was using a `std::vector` of fixed-size matrices was the key. Thanks very much for the request for a minimal example, @rex. While preparing the example, I found out the following.

For certain large input sizes (of the `std::vector` containing the matrices), Eigen throws a runtime error, which led me to [this](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicStlContainers.html) site. Following the instructions there fixed the issue.

Essentially, `std::vector` with its standard allocator seems to mess with Eigen's alignment requirements for vectorization of fixed-size array operations. Using Eigen's provided `aligned_allocator` fixes the issue.